# Find and Replace String Error

Tags: regex, powershell, str-replace

Problem

A "Find and Replace" function is deleting the contents of files instead of doing as intended.

Details

I am working in PowerShell with Regex values and have a function designed to find a specific regex string and replace it with another. Initially, the function worked just fine; however, now it is removing all the contents of the target files and saving them as empty files. I have attempted for several hours to figure out what is wrong. Unfortunately, I did not save a copy of the function when it was working as intended, so I have nothing to compare it do and most of my troubleshooting has failed. I am hoping another set of eyes can help spot the issue.

Code:

```
Function StringReplace
{
   $files = GCI -path "$path\*.config" -Recurse | where-object -InputObject $_ -Pattern ([regex]::Escape($oldString)) -Quiet) -eq $true)
   foreach ($file in $files) { 
      (GC $file.PSPath) | 
      foreach-object { $_.Replace($oldString, $newString) | 
         set-content $file.PSPath 
      }
}

$oldString = "s+r/ng"
$newString = "s/R+ng"
$path = "C:\*\somefoldername"
```

During much of my troubleshoot, I found that the all the $values were as intended; however, upon reaching Get-Content, something happens and the $file values are replicated so that there is roughly 20 copies of each file/content stored. I am not sure what it is I am doing wrong, but I would greatly appreciate any and all input.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just needed a step back from the application.

For anyone else that encounters this issue, the resolution was simple.

During the "ForEach-Object" section of the code, it needs to be altered as such:

```
foreach ($file in $files) { 
  (GC $file.PSPath) | 
  foreach-object { $_.Replace($oldString, $newString) } | 
  set-content $file.PSPath
```

The issue itself was where the } was placed.
This part of the function needed to end before saving the contents.

Comment: In cases where you may indeed want to pipe the strings out manually one-by-one, you can use `Add-Content` or `Out-File -Append` in place of `Set-Content`